# Convert Integer to hex values in PHP

Tags: php

How can I convert the numbers in the first class in PHP into the numbers in the second class, is there a built in function to convert the numbers?  Also is my title "
**Convert Integer to hex values**" even correct?

```
class Permission {
    const READ         = 1;
    const UPDATE       = 2;
    const DELETE       = 4;
    const COMMENT      = 8;
    const GRANT        = 16;
    const UNDELETE     = 32;
    const WHATEVER     = 64;
}
```

into this

```
class Permission {
    const READ     = 0x0001;
    const UPDATE   = 0x0002;
    const DELETE   = 0x0004;
    const COMMENT  = 0x0008;
    const GRANT    = 0x0010;
    const UNDELETE = 0x0020;
    const WHATEVER = 0x0040;
}
```

### **UPDATE**

To elaborate a little more of what I am trying to do.
 I currently use the first class with a bitmask class for settings,
 somebody suggested to me to change to the format in the second class though.
  However I did not know how they came up with the **0x0020** style numbers from the numbers in my 1st class.

I now see how to get the **20** from **32** but I do not know how or why they had added **0x00** in front of it to make **0x0020** to replace my original **32**

Comment: Why do you need them converted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little confused here... 0x01 = 1.
0x020 = 32, etc.

Are you looking for some of the string formatters like available in printf/sprintf?  You can use the %x marker to output hex values.

edit: Also, yes, your conversions are correct.

Comment: The zeroes only increase readability.  You would generally pad your hexadecimal numbers with zeroes to visually show their size (byte, word, dword, etc) but it is not required.  0x20 = 0x0020 = 0x0000020 = 32 decimal.

Answer (score 4):

You want:

`dechex()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php

Which is decimal to hex.

Answer (score 4):

You can't just type in the hex numbers to begin with?

Try [sprintf()](http://php.net/printf)/[printf()](http://php.net/printf) to conver them on the fly:

```
printf('%x', 42); // 2a
```

Comment: Oh I see so something like printf('0x00%x', 64); would give the result, thanks