# PHP Convert int to HEX

Tags: php, hex, pack

How can I get a similar function with pack/unpack (or other short function)?

```
function getHEX($number) {
    switch($number) {
        case 0: $ret = "\x00\x00\x00\x00"; break;
        case 1: $ret = "\x00\x00\x00\x01"; break;
        case 2: $ret = "\x00\x00\x00\x02"; break;
        case 3: $ret = "\x00\x00\x00\x03"; break;
        // (...)

        default: $ret = "\x00\x00\x00\x00";
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629386/convert-integer-to-hex-values-in-php

Answer (score 5):

You could do it with [**`dechex`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php) in PHP:

```
<?php
echo dechex(10) . "\n";
echo dechex(47);
?>
```

Comment: I tried this but the return value must be 4 bytes. When $ number is 1 calls me only 1 Byte

Answer (score 5):

Here is a hint:

```
str_pad(dechex($number), 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

Answer (score 4):

This function has solved my problem

```
pack("H*", sprintf("%08X", $number));
```

Comment: `echo chr($number);`